# Закругленные края у кнопки

Tags: java, android

Подскажите пожалуйста как закруглить края у кнопки  или какого-либо другого обьекта

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Напишите в папке `drawable` такой `xml`:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#0ff"/> //цвет по вкусу
    <size android:width="100dp" android:height="100dp"/> //размер по вкусу

    <!--Так (каждый угол по отдельности)-->
    <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="20dp" android:topRightRadius="20dp"/>

    <!--Или так (все углы за раз)-->
    <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

и присваиваете нужному объекту атрибут `android:background="@drawable/my_back"`

В случае с кнопкой (и многих других view) при кастомном бэке лучше задавать `margin`, чтобы элементы не наползали друг на друга

Comment: что значит так угол по отдельности и или так все углы за раз

Comment: я просто новичок

Comment: Если вы хотите сделать все углы с одинаковым закруглением, используйте второй вариант. Если хотите сделать разные радиусы или формы (типа "капелька" или "щит") - делайте по первому варианту, настраивая каждый угол по отдельности. Невыбранный вариант, соответственно, из `xml` удалите.